How to Get Device ICCID in flutter?
How to get the ICCID number of a sim card inside a mobile in flutter? Is there any package that can be made use of to retrieve the same? I looked for it but could find packages to get the number only but not the ICCID number.

Hi I don't think there is a package to get the ICCID number using flutter but you can get the same using the custom code which include some native code
here is the dart code:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SimInfo {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('sim_info');

  static Future<String> getIccid() async {
    try {
      final String iccid = await _channel.invokeMethod('getIccid');
      return iccid;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to get ICCID: '${e.message}'.");
      return null;
    }
  }
}

Android native code:
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;

public class SimInfoPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
    private Context applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
        applicationContext = flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext();
        final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), "sim_info");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
        if (call.method.equals("getIccid")) {
            result.success(getIccid());
        } else {
            result.notImplemented();
        }
    }

    private String getIccid() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephonyManager != null) {
            return telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
    }
}

Swfit(ios) code:
import Flutter
import UIKit

public class SwiftSimInfoPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "sim_info", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = SwiftSimInfoPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    if call.method == "getIccid" {
      result(getIccid())
    } else {
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  }

  private func getIccid() -> String? {
    let telephonyInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    if let carrier = telephonyInfo.subscriberCellularProvider {
      return carrier.iccAuthenticationKey
    }
    return nil
  }
}

Hope it works!!!!!
Happy coding
